# Getting Current AsyncApexJob at Runtime

Tags: apex, queueable-apex

I'm trying to get the current AsyncApexJob.

Using `Request.getCurrent().getRequestId()` and `Request.getCurrent().getQuiddity()` gets me that it is a Queueable that is running, but I'm looking for the specific job.

Using `System.URL.getCurrentRequestUrl()` gets a URL like the following example:

`Url:[delegate=https://customer-app-7118-dev-ed.scratch.my.salesforce.com/mockRequest/QueuedApexJob/{OrgId}/{AsyncApexJobId}/1671569802476]`

I can get the information I want from this URL, but I can't find any documentation that specifies if this is always true.  Also parsing indexes of a URL path doesn't feel right.

Is there a cleaner way to get the AsyncApexJobId in Apex? Or any documentation that I can use to justify parsing the URL?

Additional Info:

I'm working outside of the Queueable itself so I don't have the QueueableContext.

I'm trying to sync some data with an outside source.  The Queueable will pull data down and update the object.  There is also a trigger on the object that will push updates to the source.  In the trigger I'm trying to check if the update came from the Queueable so I can skip it so I'm not just sending back the exact same data that I received.

Comment: if a queueable, can't you use QueueableContext class method `getJobId()`

Comment: I'm outside of the Queueable itself so I don't have the QueueableContext.  I'm trying to sync some data with an outside source.  The Queueable will pull data down and update the object.  And I have a trigger on the object that will push updates to the source.  In the trigger I'm trying to check if the update came from the Queueable so I can skip it so I'm not just sending back the exact same data that I received.

Comment: save the queueableContext in some static variable in a service class - then the rest of your code has access to it

Comment: That is a ridiculously simple answer that works perfectly.  Thanks. I guess I was just overthinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QueueableContext` variable supplied to the queueable's `execute()` method has a method getJobId() that returns the `AsyncApexJob.Id`

```
public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {
  Id jobId = qc.getJobId();
  ...
}
```

Since you stated you need to know this later down the execution chain and don't want to pass the `qc` variable through all of the method calls, I suggest the following:

Create a class called `TransactionState`

```
public class TransactionState {
  public static QueueableContext qc {
     get {return qc;}
     set;
  }
}
```

Then change you queueable execute() to:

```
public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {
  TransactionState.qc = qc;
  ...
}
```

and your other classes simply get the jobId

```
public MyClass {
  public void myMethod() {
    ...
    Id jobId = TransactionState.qc.getJobId();
    ...
 }
}
```

This has other advantages as you can mock the value of `TransactionState.qc` in testmethods so you can do downstream unit testing without having to actually start a queueable.

That is, a testmethod can mock a QueueableContext as follows

```
class MockQueueableContext implements System.QueueableContext {

    public Id getJobId() { // valid Id, or query one 
     return '707000000000000';
    }

}
```

and use the mock

```
TransactionState.qc = new MockQueueableContext();
```

before doing your code-under-test execution.

Or, more advanced, dependency inject in a mock AsyncApexJob.Id

```
class MockQueueableContext implements System.QueueableContext {
    Id mockAsyncApexJobId;
    public Id getJobId() { // valid Id, or query one 
     return mockAsyncApexJobId;
    }

}

TransactionState.qc = new MockQueueableContext(someMockAsyncApexJob.Id);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer from @cropredy.  Thank you for the super simple response.

I created a static QueueableContext variable in my trigger handler class.

In the Queueable class itself, assign the QueueableContext to the static variable in the handler.

Then in the handler you can use the context.getJobId() method.